# Change Rails date type format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am saving dates with the followings formats 1985-01-04 and 19850104, then I need to show the format Year of this way **1985 January 4.**

but, i got this  **got: 04 January 1985.**

could I change this format? I'm using rails 6.
I have wanted to change this option default because I am implement testing with this format: **1985 January 4.**

Comment: Look into I18n (Internationalization) and l10n (Localization) here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: The basic form is `<%= l your_model.datetime %>` in your template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 'strftime' to format a date for your needs:

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y %B %d")
```

See this cheat sheet for many other options of date formatting with strftime:
https://www.shortcutfoo.com/app/dojos/ruby-date-format-strftime/cheatsheet

Comment: Glad it helped! you can accept the answer if it solved your issue :)